# Skip autocompleted brackets, commas etc. with tab in sublime-text

Tags: sublimetext2

In sublime, if you type, `alert("{<cursor>` it will autocomplete the closing brackets and quotes to: `alert("{<cursor>}")`.

In visual studio, if you hit tab, it will place the cursor at the end of the autocompleted characters.

How can I replicate this exact behaviour in sublime? I don't see much point in autocompletion if you have to type those characters anyway or use arrow keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @AGS's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953997/1426065) and your comment, there are two possible options. The first (if you're not using OS X) is to just hit <kbd>End</kbd>, which will move the cursor to the end of the line (`eol`).

The second option is to slightly modify @AGS's keymap to the following:

```json
{ 
    "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\"\\]\\}\\$]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]   
}
```

The binds the `eol` functionality to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and includes the regex support, which can be removed if you want.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't a perfect solution if you already have other text on the line after the `alert("{<cursor>}")`, if you need to modify it for that use case just let me know.

Comment: That would be nice but this will do just fine in 99% of cases so marking it as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `.sublime-keymap` file and add

```
// Skip past round and square autocomplete brackets
    { 
        "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\"\\]\\}\\$]", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
        ]   
    },
```

In this case, `shift + enter` will function like `tab` in visual studio.

The solution is originally not mine - I found it either here or on the ST2 forum.

Comment: This moves one over one character at a time, is there any way to actually skip over all of them?