# Sublime Text - Keyboard shortcut to go to next line or end of line after autocomplete?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 2 (or 3), is there a keyboard shortcut of some sort (tab? enter?) to go from the cursor denoted by `|`:

`$var->catch('someName|');`

to

`$var->catch('someName');|`

or

```
$var->catch('someName');
|
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first scenario, you can modify this answer slightly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19957050/1569064  (note the addition of the single quote, `'`, and the semi-colon `;`, in the `operand` values

```json
// Move to end of line
   { 
    "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\"';\\]\\}\\$]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]   
},
// Move to next line
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+enter"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "stops", "empty_line": true, "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\"';\\]\\}\\$]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]   
}
```

My answer for your second example works when there is an empty line below.  Otherwise, it moves the cursor to the end of that next, non-empty line.